# Parse string to get digits before and after particular character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse digits before and after `X` from this string, but unable to get all the digits. Can someone help me pointing out what I am missing here?

```
>>> import re
>>> f = "abc_xyz1024X137M4B4abc_xyz"
>>> re.findall(".*\w+(\d+)X(\d+).*", f)
[('4', '137')]
```

Comment: Do you only want the digits **directly** before and after the `X` or all digits?

Comment: What is your desired output? It seems there could be two possibilities: `('1024', '137')`, or `('1024', ['137', '4', '4'])`.

Comment: The problem is the `\w+` there is going to soak up as many word characters as possible—and digits are word characters. Just take that out and you'll get what you want. (Or replace it with a class that captures all word characters except digits, but I'm not sure why you needed anything there in the first place…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `.*\w+(\d+)X(\d+).*` first grabs all the 0+ chars as many as possible (the whole string) and then backracks trying to match the subsequent patterns. `\w+` backtracks up to the point where the next char is a digit before `X`, so the first capturing group only contains the single digit before `X`, and the second one contains all the digits after `X`. Check [this `.*\w+(\d+)X(\d+).*` debugger page](https://regex101.com/r/2sofRe/2/debugger).

You should only match and capture the digits, then match the `X` and then again match and capture the digits.

You may use

```
import re
f = "abc_xyz1024X137M4B4abc_xyz"
print(re.findall(r"(\d+)X(\d+)", f))
# => [('1024', '137')]
```

Or, if you are only interested in a *single* match:

```
m = re.search(r"(?P<x>\d+)X(?P<y>\d+)", f)
if m:
    print(m.groupdict()) # => {'y': '137', 'x': '1024'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JhRtV5) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2sofRe/1).

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, another option is to split the string on the character `"X"`. Then find the last set of consecutive digits in the left half of the split and the first set of consecutive digits in the right half of the split.

For example:

```
import re
f = "abc_xyz1024X137M4B4abc_xyz"

left, right = f.split("X")
print(right)
#137M4B4abc_xyz

print(left)
#abc_xyz1024

print((re.findall('\d+', left)[-1], re.findall('\d+', right)[0]))
#('1024', '137')
```